# Excel issue using datedif function

Tags: excel

I have a homework assignment that is to calculate the number of days between dates. It is a simple problem; however the format of the dates in column D are causing issue because of the date function. I am using DATEDIF but I am getting a name error. D is formatted as such =DATE(16,1,6), the E is =TODAY() and the datedif is =DATEDIF(D8,E3,D). Please help. =E3-D8 returns the serial 36548.

Comment: So what is your question? The difference between today (01/29/2016) and `Date(16, 1, 6)` (01/06/1916) is 36,548 days.

Comment: The `#NAME?` error is from the third argument in your function.  Excel does not know what `D` represents.  For you function, you should be using a string, or a variable that refers to a string.  You probably want `"D"`.  But note that for days difference, simple subtraction (as noted by @KenWhite) works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

=DATEDIF(D8,E3,"D")

[image]

Otherwise the **D** is not a Defined Name.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the correct value. The number of days between January 6, 1916 (`=DATE(16, 1, 6)`) and January 29, 2016 (`=TODAY()`) is 36,548 days.Your subtraction using `=E3-D8` is returning the correct value.

You can do a rough approximation yourself:

```
 365.25 days per year
x   100 years
=======
36,525 days
```

Comment: Excel has had a `DATEDIF` function for many years.  It is not documented and does have some quirks.  But it is still present.  You can find information at Chip Pearson's web site for the [DateDif Function](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/datedif.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Interesting. Neither Excel XP or Excel 2013 are aware of it, so it's pretty strange that it's had it for many years. (I've checked both, and neither of them accept it, suggest it when you type `=Date` into the cell, or offer the parameters when you type `=DateDiff(`.) What specific versions are those *many years* in?

Comment: Did you type it in, with the arguments?  (and only one `F`).  The function wizard does not prompt it.  I have seen and used it in Excel 97, 2007 and 2016.  But it has been present since 95.  I note that in 2016, although there is no prompt at the function wizard, once the dialog box opens, you can select Help and it brings up a Help screen which also states *Applies To: Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2010, Excel 2007, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for Mac 2011, Excel Online, SharePoint Server 2010, SharePoint Foundation 2010, Excel Starter, SharePoint Server, SharePoint Server 2007*

Comment: Let me emphasize -- `DATEDIF`  not `DATEDIFF`

Comment: I tried in both versions, with `=DateDiff(C1, A1, "d")`, and the result in both was `#NAME?`. I removed the first paragraph from my answer, so it's really not relevant any longer, but I'm asking for my own education for future reference. (Apologies for the somewhat impolite phrasing in the question in my last comment. Wasn't intended to be rude - just badly phrased.) Using `=DATEDIF(C1, A1, "d")` (one F) results in `#NUM!`instead.

Comment: You are entering the function incorrectly -- DateDif only has one `**F**`; you are using two.

Comment: @Ron: Read my last comment again, which specifically says I tried with both F and FF, neither of which works. Bringing up the function wizard offers a link to help for the function, which takes me to the help contents. Searching for *DateDif* brings me to *Calculating the difference between two dates*, which recommends using `=A3-A2` for days between or =NetworkDays(A3,A2)` for weekdays between, or `=MONTH` for months between, etc. No mention of either spelling of DateDif/DateDiff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102051/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-ken-white).